# MongoDB aggregation: How to query a limited amount of "top" documents per group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have a MongoDB collection with documents about employees:

```
{
  name : "John Doe",
  department : "Finance",
  salary : 100
}
```

How can I query the X employees with the highest salaries per department?

**Edit**

Just to make myself a bit more clear, this is how I thought to achieve the result:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$sort : {salary : -1}},
    {$group : {
        _id : "$department"
        employees : {$addToSet : "$name"}
    },
    {$project : {employees : {$slice : X}}}
)
```

But this won't work for two reasons:
 1. $addToSet doesn't guarantee any ordering of the output set (at least according to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)).
 2. [$slice doesn't work in the aggregation framework](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074).

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a single query/aggregation as it requires more than one pass to resolve the answer (first get the distinct departments, then ...).

Answer (score 1):

While it's not the best performance, you can achieve this returning the collection and then sorting / taking in code. If you want it by the command line, something like

```
db.collection.find({ Department : 'Sales' }).sort({Salary:-1}).limit(50)
```

should work.

Comment: I assume that by querying the entire collection and handling the data in the code I can achieve anything (with varying performance). I want to be able to that in the shell, and with the best performance. The query you provided completely ignores the departments; thus, it is irrelevant.

Comment: The format of the command should work fine - it's not based upon the idea of fetching the whole collection. Sorry if the example wasn't tailored well enough:

Comment: I know. My comment was a two points comment, much like your answer. Anyway, the query you provided doesn't answer the problem in the question (not necessarily the example I presented). I've edited the question with my thoughts on how to solve it and why my solution won't work; it might help understand my problem a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following query should help you to solve your problem.

By using aggregate query, you can first sort data, then by using limit you limit the number of users with highest salary you want. At the end, you can group users by their department.

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$sort : {salary : -1}},
  {$limit : 5},
  {$group : {_id:"$department", employees : {$addToSet : "$name"}}}
)
```

Comment: This will return the X employees with the highest salary amongst all employees grouped by their department. It is not the same as the X employees with the highest salary in each department (which is what I'm looking for).